# Combine Results from MS Access and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access, asp-classic

I would like to know if it is possible to combine the results of two different databases, MS Access and SQL Server.

Here is what I am trying to do:

SELECT EVERYTHNIG BETWEEN TWO DATES FROM THE SQL Server 2008 R2 EXPRESS) TABLE CALLED LOADS

```
    '//THIS WOULD BE THE SQL Server DATABASE

    strQueryMSSQL = "Select * FROM LOADS WHERE PUP_DATE >= '" & strPUPDate & "' and DEL_DATE <= '" & strDELDate & "'" ORDER BY PUP_DATE DESC"
    objMSSQL.Open strQueryMSSQL 

  '//THIS WILL LOOP AND SHOW THE DATE/TIME IN THE SQL Server DB
    while not objMSSQL.EOF
    Response.write objMSSQL("PUDATETIMEFLD")
    objMSSQL.MoveNext
    wend

    Example Result(s):
    DATE/TIME:
    02/01/2012 1:00pm
    02/02/2012 7:00am
    02/03/2012 9:00pm
    02/04/2012 6:00am
    02/06/2012 8:28am
```

NOW, SELECT EVERYTHING BETWEEN TWO DATES FROM THE (MS ACCESS DB) TABLE CALLED FuelDetail

```
'//THIS WOULD BE THE MS ACCESS DATABASE

strQueryMSAccess = "Select * FROM FuelDetail WHERE PICK_UP_DATE >= #" & strPickupDate & "# and TransactionDate <= #" & TransactionDate & "#" ORDER BY TransactionDate,TransactionTime DESC"
objMSACCESS.Open strQueryMSAccess 

'//THIS WILL LOOP AND SHOW THE DATE/TIME IN THE MS ACCESS DB
while not objMSACCESS.EOF
Response.write objMSACCESS("PICKUPDATE_FLD")
objMSACCESS.MoveNext
wend

Example Result(s):
DATE/TIME:
02/02/2012 7:30am
02/03/2012 11:50pm
02/05/2012 7:00pm
02/05/2012 7:05pm
02/07/2012 6:57am
```

But I would like to combine them (by: date/time) and show the results together as if they where in a single database.

When you loop it would look something like this.

```
Example Result(s):
DATE/TIME:
02/01/2012 1:00pm   <-- This is from the MS SQL DB
02/02/2012 7:00am   <-- This is from the MS SQL DB
02/02/2012 7:30am   <-- This is from the MS ACCESS DB
02/03/2012 9:00pm   <-- This is from the MS SQL DB
02/03/2012 11:50pm      <-- This is from the MS ACCESS DB
02/04/2012 6:00am   <-- This is from the MS SQL DB
02/05/2012 7:00pm   <-- This is from the MS ACCESS DB
02/05/2012 7:05pm   <-- This is from the MS ACCESS DB
02/06/2012 8:28am   <-- This is from the MS SQL DB
02/07/2012 6:57am   <-- This is from the MS ACCESS DB
```

Thanks so much for any help with my problem/question.

(Edit) Added:...

Maybe something like this:

```
dim strAccess
dim strSQL
dim strDateNTimes
strAccess=CDate(objMSACCESS("PICKUPDATE_FLD"))
strSQL=CDate(objMSSQL("PUDATETIMEFLD"))

'//THIS WILL LOOP AND SHOW THE DATE/TIME IN THE MS ACCESS DB 
while not objMSACCESS.EOF 
strDateNTimes=strDateNTimes & "," & objMSACCESS("PICKUPDATE_FLD")  & "," 
objMSACCESS.MoveNext 
wend 

'//THIS WILL LOOP AND SHOW THE DATE/TIME IN THE SQL Server DB 
while not objMSSQL.EOF 
strDateNTimes=strDateNTimes & "," & objMSACCESS("PUDATETIMEFLD")  & "," 
objMSSQL.MoveNext 
wend 

'// Now just split the commas and do what you will with the date

ArrayOfValues = Split(strDateNTimes, ", ")

For i = 0 To UBound(ArrayOfValues)
 Response.Write "Value " & i & " is " & ArrayOfValues(i) & "<br>"
 Next
```

Comment: I don't know much of ASP, only Access and SQL Server, but for me, the easiest way is either to link the SQL Server tables in you .MDB and treat them as you would treat any Access table, or link the Access tables into you SQL Server and do it all through SS.

Comment: Why not create a view in SQL with the MSAccess and the SQL data together, then write them back out in a single query?

I've never created a SQL Query into Access from MSSQL, so I'm unsure if it is possible - but it is ODBC, so I'm assuming it's possible.  I would like to think so.

Comment: Or rather - the other way around.  Link your SQL Data into your Access DB and take it from there. - As @iDevlop has stated.

Comment: @iDevlop I didnt know that I can link the Access tables into the SQL DB. Thx.

Comment: @RogueSpear00 how is that possbile ? I would like that solution the most.

Comment: What version of MS Access are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest linking your SQL Table into MS Access, as that seems to be the "quickest" way to get a single data set.

You can see how to link SQL data into MS Access [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/import-or-link-to-sql-server-data-HA010200494.aspx#BM2)

From there, create one VIEW that connects both data from MS Access, and `SQL` into one `VIEW`, and output your results from that table in the fashion you choose.